# Neo4j failed to start after unmanaged extension entry made to conf file

Tags: neo4j, graphql

I have neo4j 3.2.2 up and running on Windows 10 but when I tried to add neo4j-graphql extension the database failed to start after I add the line 
dbms.unmanaged_extension_classes=org.neo4j.graphql=/graphql to the server configuration file via the options button on the startup window. Also...the link to download the plugin in the neo4j github

GitHub.com/neo4j-graphql/neo4j-graphql/releases

has no releases.

The error I receive is:
Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer$ServerComponentsLifecycleAdapter@44dc8158' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Multiple exceptions".

Comment: you are probably using a version for 3.1, go  to branch 3.2 here https://github.com/neo4j-graphql/neo4j-graphql/tree/3.2 and build yourself a plugin for 3.2.2 neo4j

Comment: @TomažBratanič ...No I actually used this link for the installation using the following: git clone https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-graphql
cd neo4j-graphql
mvn clean package
cp target/neo4j-graphql-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar $NEO4J_HOME/plugins
echo 'dbms.unmanaged_extension_classes=org.neo4j.graphql=/graphql' >> $NEO4J_HOME/conf/neo4j.conf
$NEO4J_HOME/bin/neo4j restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current default branch for this repository (`master`) targets [Neo4j version 3.1.3](https://github.com/neo4j-graphql/neo4j-graphql/blob/master/pom.xml#L23). For a version of the plugin targeting Neo4j 3.2.x be sure to checkout out the `3.2` branch of the repo before building:

```
git fetch
git checkout 3.2
mvn clean package
```

Comment: Thanks guys. I did get the plugin loaded using the 3.2 branch...without the conf file entry. Apparently its not needed.

Comment: UPDATE:....The conf entry is needed after all for the @Cypher to work. The problem was related to the location of the .jar file. Apparently depending on the download of neo4j i.e. ZIP, or EXE for Windows the plugin folder is located in different places. I used the .EXE download and in order to get the dbms.unmanaged_extension... entry to work you have to place the .jar file in c:/program files/neo4j/plugin folder if that's where you installed neo4j.

Comment: I still have a puzzle though! The Neo4j browser won't recognize the  3.2 .jar file unless I place it in a  .grapghdb/plugin folder